# $\log|x|\in\text{BMO}(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Lemma. $A$ is fixed. For any ball $B$, there exists a constant $c_B$, which satisfies
>   $$\frac{1}{B}\int_B|f-c_B|\leq A$$
>   then we have $f\in\text{BMO}(R^n)$.

I want use the lemma to prove the facts below:
$$\log|x|\in\text{BMO}(\mathbb R^n)$$

We should prove that for all $x_0$ and $R>0$, there exists a constant $c_{x_0,R}$, which satisfies
$$\frac{1}{|B_R(x_0)|}\int_{B_R(x_0)}|\log|x|-c_{x_0,R}|\leq A$$

I am stuck at how we find the $c_{x_0,R}$. I try to make a transformation to the integral
$$\frac{1}{|B_R(x_0)|}\int_{B_R(x_0)}|\log|x|-c_{x_0,R}|$$
$$=\frac{n}{\omega_nR^n}\int_{B_R(x_0)}|\log|x|-c_{x_0,R}|$$
$$=\frac{n}{\omega_nR^n}\int_{B_R(x_0)}|\log|x|-c_{x_0,R}|$$
$$=\frac{n}{\omega_n}\int_{B_1(0)}|\log|Rz+x_0|-c_{x_0,R}|$$
then I have no idea.

Any advice is helpful. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- If $|x_0|<2R$, then for $z_0:=-\frac{x_0}{R}$, 
  $$\log|Rz+x_0|-\log R=\log|z-z_0|$$
  and $B_1(0)\subset B_3(z_0)$.
- If $|x_0|\ge 2R$, then for $z\in B_1(0)$,
  $$0< \log|Rz+x_0|-\log \frac{|x_0|}{2}<\log 3.$$